# Securing SpringBoot API for desktop application client

Tags: spring-boot, javafx, spring-security, oauth, microservices

I have a SpringBoot Micro-Service based backend API that uses Zuul as a gateway proxy between a JavaFX Desktop Application. Right now there is no security in place, but I am looking to secure the backend with Spring Security, however, every tutorial I seem to run across seems to be based on web-apps and I haven't seen anything for my particular use case. I don't know much about spring security but would like to know if I can accomplish my goals with it, and if so, what modules or examples should I be looking for.

Goals:

1. Provide a way for my API to know that requests are coming from the desktop app itself, I think the technical term for this is assigning the desktop app a client id and then having the Zuul Server validate that the client id is that off the desktop app before accepting the request. This should be the case for all requests
2. Only allow API traffic through the Zuul Proxy, all of the downstream requests to the micro-services behind the Zuul gateway should only be accepted if they are coming from the Zuul Server itself.
3. Allow requests for logging in and registering as a new user without any type of security other than the desktop client id discussed in 1.
4. When a user provides a successful username/password on login, they are returned a JWT which is then stored in the JavaFX application and used for all of the other requests to the backend.
5. Configure the token to expire after a specific time frame, say like 90 minutes and provide a method for automatically refreshing an expired token as long as the users account is still valid. For this, I don't want the user to have to re-login, I just want it to check behind the scenes to make sure their account is still valid and then issue a new token if needed.
6. Have user based roles so certain features, methods, endpoints, etc. are only accessible to users with the valid role. Within the GUI these features will be hidden or disabled, but I would still like a layer of security on the server side to protect against unwanted access in case someone was able to modify the app.

Comment: you should put a bounty on that question :D

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing down answers to each of your goals :

1. Passing the client Id in every request from desktop application doesnt make sense, instead you client Id and secret can be passed during authenticaiton call, Like we have in Oauth 2.0 framework. Rest https calls should be made from client, So to avoid tampering of request, You can also go for mutual SSL between your client application and Zuul API gateway, It assures that call is coming from Desktop client only.
2. Yes, Zuul api gateway should be single entry point to your application, Your internal microservices should not be exposed to public.
3. For user registeration, Client authentication can be achieved using client Id and secret
4. Correct, You can also create http only cookie at backend, which will include your jwt token only.
5. Token refresh can be achieved at zuul api gateway, if session is active, make call to refresh token endpoint to get new access token.
6. On server side, At zuul proxy you can validate the incoming bearer token expiry along with signature validation, with generic claims too. Now at microservices level spring security can be used for role based access control for particular methods.